# Token Base authentication returns 401 unauthorized response in Blazor WASM

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, blazor-webassembly, bearer-token

I'm developing a new project using Blazor WASM and an API and using token-based authentication for my project. But something interesting happened in the project and I decided to share it with you guys and hear your experiences and help.

When I send my username and password to the API and get the success response plus token I save the token in the browser's local storage plus the user information.

```
`public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authStateProvider;
    private readonly IRequestFactory _requestFactory;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public AuthenticationService(ILocalStorageService localStorage,
                                AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider,
                                IRequestFactory requestFactory,
                                HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _authStateProvider = authStateProvider;
        _localStorage = localStorage;
        _requestFactory = requestFactory;
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<APIResponseViewModel> LoginAsync(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        var response = await _requestFactory.CallAPIAsync<LoginViewModel>(model, "/api/account/login", HttpMethod.Post);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponseViewModel>(response.ReturnValue);
        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            await _localStorage.SetItemAsync(ReadOnlyStrings.Local_Token, result.Token);
            await _localStorage.SetItemAsync(ReadOnlyStrings.Local_UserDetails, result.UserViewModel);
            ((AuthStateProvider)_authStateProvider).NotifyUserLoggedIn(result.Token);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.Token);
        }
        return response;
    }
}`
```

I set my HTTPClient default header authorization with my token in the login method that the code works perfectly fine,

As you can see I have a generic method which is responsible for sending the request to the server and get the response back called  `_requestFactory.CallAPIAsync` which is:

```
public RequestFactory(ILocalStorageService local, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _local = local;
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}

public async Task<APIResponseViewModel> CallAPIAsync<TRequest>(TRequest? request, string url, HttpMethod httpMethod)
{
var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = httpMethod,
    RequestUri = new Uri(ReadOnlyStrings.BaseApiUrl + url)
};

var token = await _local.GetItemAsStringAsync(ReadOnlyStrings.Local_Token);

if (request != null)
{
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
    httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}

var httpResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);

var data = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<APIResponseViewModel>(data);

return result;
}
```

the problem is when I move the:

`_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", myTokenFromILocalStorage);`

to the CallAPIAsync the server doesn't recognize it and return 401 response.

I checked the watch list and my token is in my _httpClient but still server returns back 401.

Any Idea?